# returning base64 string from Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Very Basically I have an image I have converted into a Base64 string. The following code is how it is turned into a base64string and how im trying to return it. It is a modification of a phonegap plugin so please excuse the naming of certain things.

```
package org.apache.cordova;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;



public class Screenshot extends Plugin {

    @Override

    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        // starting on ICS, some WebView methods
        // can only be called on UI threads
        final Plugin that = this;
        final String id = callbackId;
        super.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            //@Override
            @TargetApi(8)
            public void run() {
                View view = webView.getRootView();

                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
                view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures");
                if (!folder.exists()) {
                    folder.mkdirs();

                }

                File f = new File(folder, "screenshot_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
                System.out.println(folder);
                System.out.println("screenshot_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");



                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                String base64String = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
                String mytextstring = "data:image/png;base64,"+base64String;
                System.out.println(mytextstring);

                that.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK), mytextstring);
            }
        });

        PluginResult imageData = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        imageData.setKeepCallback(true);
        System.out.println("imageData:==================================================================================>>>>>"+imageData);
        return imageData;
    }

}
```

This line:

```
System.out.println(mytextstring);
```

outputs the base64 string, however this line:

```
System.out.println("imageData:==================================================================================>>>>>"+imageData);
```

doesn't. I'm trying to get imageData to contain the base64string to I can return that and use it in some Javascript. i have played about with the code for a while now with no success, I am new to Java so really don't know how close I am. Can anyone guide me please?

**EDIT** Simply all I want to do is return the Base64String, nothing else.

Comment: We don't have enough code to tell. This seems to be related to the callback system.

Comment: you created imageData but you didnt set mytextstring to it.

Comment: I have included the full code for the java, and the PluginResult method/function.

Comment: What's the actual output and the toString() implementation of PlugInResult?

Comment: The actual output of the prints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code that calls this.success is incorrect. It should be:

```
that.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, mytextstring), id);
```

The way you have it:

```
that.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK), mytextstring);
```

Tells the callback server to call the success callback at "mytextstring". Obviously there is no callback stored at "mytextstring" as that is your result.

In addition the default .js file for the screen shot plugin does not provide a way for you to call it with success/failure callbacks. So you will need to modify the .js code in order to get a success callback invoked with your base64 data. Add something like this to Screenshot.js:

```
Screenshot.prototype.getBase64Screenshot = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "Screenshot", "saveScreenshot", []);
};
```

Then you can call it by doing this:

```
window.plugins.screenshot.getBase64Screenshot(function(data) {
    console.log("Data = " + data);
}, function() {
    console.log("We got an error");
});
```

Obviously you'd provide your own success and failure callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a mistake in your code. I'll try to provide a couple of ways from the point of view of pure java

When you create your 'PluginResult' object you don't connect it in any manner to the string you've created (base64string variable).

If you want to return the base64-encoded string you should do something like:

```
PluginResult imageData = new PluginResult(..., ...,  base64string, ..., ...)
```

or if you don't have a constructor try to use setter like this (for example):

```
PlugingResult imageData  = new PlugingResult(...)
imageData.setEncodedString(imageData)
```

Without an exposed API its hard to understand how to use object of type PluginResult properly (I've never used it by myself)

If you see that nothing suits your needs but you absolutely have to use the PluginResult object, than you may consider to create a class that contains both PluginResult and your encoded String  and use  it as a return type of your method. Like this:

```
class MyPluginResult {
   private PluginResult pluginResult;
   private String encodedString;
   /*
    ....

     getters/setters/constructors go here
    */
}
```

Than make your method returning MyPluginResult, change the code that creates a PluginResult and returns it and you'll be fine.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about Cordova and PhoneGap, but looking through the API you have the constructor  `public PluginResult(Status status, String message)`.
 
 I guess you can pass the `base64String` to the second parameter of that constructor. The message is converted to a JSON string format, but you can handle that format in java / javascript easily.

Hope this helps.
Regards